# Plot a circle on Spherical surface

Tags: plotting

How do I can plot a circle on a sphere using Mathematica code? I would like to draw small and great circles for arbitrary orientation on spherical surface.

Comment: I would like to know about not only great circle but also on small circle for arbitrary orientation along which both the theta and phi (spherical polar coordinates) are varied. Moreover, I would like to see this without 'manipulate' command. I need to generate a static image